# Why is the electric potential across a capacitor zero after a long time?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, capacitance

I was just exposed to this concept in class, that the electric potential across a capacitor is zero after a long period of time, but it was never explained why. This is for an RC circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The potential difference, $V$, between the plates of the capacitor is also the potential difference across the resistor, because the resistor is connected across the capacitor (assuming that this RC circuit consists just of the R and the C).

The pd $V$ will drive a current ($I=V/R$) through the resistor. This current can only be a flow of electrons from the negatively charged plate of the capacitor to the positively charged plate.

So the capacitor plates will gradually lose their charges. This process will go on and on. The current, that is the rate of loss of charge, will get less and less because the charge, ±$Q$ will get less and less, and so will $V$, because $V=Q/C$, but the charge, and therefore the p.d. will clearly eventually approach zero. Strictly it will take an infinite time for them ever to *reach* zero, but they will be as close to zero as we care to choose in a finite time. For example, in a time equal to $14\ RC$, the charge  on each plate, and therefore $V$, will have fallen to roughly a millionth of its initial value.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw an RC circuit without generator, and you use Kirchhoff laws, you get that the tension across the capacitor goes to zero with an exponential function with a time constant $\tau =RC$. This means that after $5 \tau$ the tension is zero for practical applications. You said long time, this is relative. For example if you have R=1KOhm and C=10^-6 F you have $5 \tau=5 ms$ . 
If you want an intuitive explanation of the phenomenon, you can think that once the circuit is closed and the current can flow, the charges on the capacitors plates will tend to go to the other plate, bringing themselves in a more stable position which is described by $V=0$.

Comment: This [page should](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit#Natural_response) help (section on natural response).